# .XmlBeanFactory got a strikethrough

Tags: spring

[image: In my code when I import XmlBeanFactory, it got a strikethrough line like this...]
In my code when I import XmlBeanFactory, it got a strikethrough line like this...

What should I do??
I have added all the jar files, that i got in C:\spring-framework-3.2.4.RELEASE-dist\spring-framework-3.2.4.RELEASE\lib  and I am using junno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the class you're using is deprecated.

In case of XmlBeanFactory [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html) say it is:

> Deprecated. as of Spring 3.1 in favor of DefaultListableBeanFactory and XmlBeanDefinitionReader

So you can either ignore the warning for now and risk breaking your code when that class is removed in some future spring version or change your code to use both `DefaultListableBeanFactory` and `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`.

The class itself is just a few lines of code that delegates to `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"serial", "all"})
public class XmlBeanFactory extends DefaultListableBeanFactory {

    private final XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(this);


    public XmlBeanFactory(Resource resource) throws BeansException {
        this(resource, null);
    }

    public XmlBeanFactory(Resource resource, BeanFactory parentBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
        super(parentBeanFactory);
        this.reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);
    }

}
```

so if you really need it in the future you can easily emulate the behavior.